# ¿por qué no me sale el mensaje de error cuando valido si el usuario ha introducido un campo vacío?

Tags: javascript, validación, function, prompt

comunidad, espero se encuentren muy bien.
En este programita para realizar un cálculo de costos he tratado de validar cuando el usuario no introduce nada, es decir, a través de un prompt con un dato vacío. Sin embargo el mensaje de error no ocurre cuando se realiza esta acción. De hecho hay una función creada para tal efecto pero veo que no anda y le he cambiado los parámetros y nada. Pensé también en declarar alguna variable que me ayudara en ello pero perdí el hilo en la lógica. ¿Podrían ayudarme por favor? Gracias de antemano

```js
let IVA = parseFloat(0.21)
let band = true

function campoVacio(precio) {
  if (precio == "") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function ingresePrecio() {
  while (band) {
    precio = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese precio a calcular IVA"));
    if (campoVacio(precio)) {
      alert("Ingrese algun numero");
    } else if (isNaN(precio)) {
      alert("Not a Number!")
    } else {
      band = false
    }
  }
  alert("el precio ingresado es $" + precio)
  return precio
}

function calculoIVA() {
  IVAcalculado = precio * IVA
  alert("El IVA del precio ingresado es de $" + IVAcalculado)
  return IVAcalculado
}

function suma() {
  precioNeto = precio + IVAcalculado
  alert("el precio total con IVA incluido es de $" + precioNeto)
  return precioNeto
}

ingresePrecio()
calculoIVA()
suma()
```

Comment: Si no digito nada en la casilla el programa me lo indica y me impide continuar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución la tienes en tu código. Si no se teclea nada en el prompt precio es NaN, por tanto la función quedaría

```
function ingresePrecio() {
  while (band) {
    precio = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese precio a calcular IVA"));
    if (isNaN(precio)) {
          alert("Ingrese algun numero");
      }
     else {
      band = false
    }
  }
  alert("el precio ingresado es $" + precio)
  return precio
}
```

Precio va a tener un valor NaN debido al parseFloat. Si quieres diferenciar entrada vacía de no numérica tendrías que cambiar el código

```
  tecleado = prompt("Ingrese precio a calcular IVA");
  precio = parseFloat(tecleado)
  if (tecleado="")  //detectas entrada vacia
```